# Capture delta table version from pyspark operation

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Looking for a safe method to capture the version number in the delta table log. I have seen a lot of methods that will work most of the time, but I am looking for something that is 100% concurrency safe.

Example of what I would like is something to the effect:

`delta_version = df.write.format('delta').save(<table>)`

Most of what I have seen is to the effect:

```
df.write.mode('append').format('delta').save(<table>)
# get latest version here
# I don't think this is safe because what if another process also just finished making an append to the table
```

I have several hacky solutions, but I am looking for a direct supported method if one exists.

Comment: afaik this is not directly possible (the save method doesn't return anything). The describe history command will give you information about user, notebook, timestamp etc which will help increase the confidence. Although not pretty you could even add custom user metadata when writing (e.g. a GUID) to be 100% sure. https://docs.databricks.com/delta/custom-metadata.html#language-python

Comment: Thanks, I will use the GUID approach.